# Type of C++ that Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 uses?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have been learning C++ for the past few years, mainly on Turbo C++ and recently using MiniGW with Code::Blocks. I use things like:

`cout << "Some random text";`

Recently, I decided to download and try Visual C++, so I could create form-based applications (GUI frontend). But the default code that greeted me was completely new:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

This is completely new for me, and I've never seen `::` in C++ code before. Can I use MiniGW to create windows forms? I don't need to run on other platforms. Also, what is a good learning resource for Microsoft's C++?

EDIT: I learned from my school in India (In 11th grade), guess the Board (CBSE) doesn't want us to know the good stuff

Comment: That's clearly the thing MS calls "managed C++", which adds integration with .NET languages.  Check your language project type settings when creating a new project and look for "native" C++.  Real C++ does use `::` though - to separate namespaces and `class`/`struct`/`union` names from their content... any introductory C++ book will cover that.

Comment: Yep. If you have never seen `::`, then whatever source you have been learning C++ from is heavily outdated and should only be used for historical research, not for learning.

Comment: "I've never seen :: in C++ code before". You need to update your C++ knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2010 it is possible from the wizard to create C++/CLI winforms, in the newer VS they removed that (atlhough it still can be done but not using the wizard).

For you to quickly get on track I would suggest just creating a dialog based MFC program to play around with.

Later you can explore 3rd party options like Qt and WTL.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is C++/CLI which is a special extension for .NET framework and not pure C++. You can't compile it using MinGW, only MSVC. To create Windows forms, you can use MFC, WinAPI or C++/CLI. Also you can take a look on Qt framework which can work with MinGW and adds some good tools for GUI programming.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose "Console application" from the types of C++ projects and you will be back to your familiar c++ world